# How to check if a file was edited/modified by a user?

Tags: file, dart, filesystems, flutter

I'm having an issue in dart/flutter, I want to check if the user opens a file and modified/edited the file, and only  if this happens I do something that is not important... for that purpose I used this chunk of code:

```
String dir = await bloc.buildFileDirectory(filePath);

File file = new File('$dir/filename');

DateTime date = await file.lastModified();

if(date.millisecondsSinceEpoch < someOtherFileTimeStamp)  
  do something
```

with the method ***lastModified()*** from  **File** class in Dart, when the user open the file, it will consider a modification, and so it will trigger the if condition... is there any functional way to check for really modifications on the file? like editing some text inside the file, or change the name...something like that

Ty for your time

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the `watcher` library's [FileWatcher](https://pub.dev/documentation/watcher/latest/watcher/FileWatcher-class.html).

Here's an example on how to use it:

```
final watcher = FileWatcher('main.dart');
final subscription = watcher.events.listen((event) {
  switch (event.type) {
    case ChangeType.ADD:
      print('Added file');
      break;
    case ChangeType.MODIFY:
      print('Modified');
      break;
    case ChangeType.REMOVE:
      print('Removed');
  }
});
```

If you need to determine whether the file changed since last time your program ran, then this will of course not work and you will have to use the timestamp as you're doing, or even hash the contents of the file and store it somewhere, so you can check later if the hash is still the same.